# How to save bulk documents in couchdb using lightcouch api in java

Tags: java, couchdb

I am using the  [lightcouch API](http://www.lightcouch.org/javadocs/index.html) to connect to couchdb through Java. I am able to save a single document using dbclient.save(object) method. However, my requirement is to save bulk documents at a time. I am not able to find any methods related to saving bulk documents using the Lightcouch api. Please suggest any possible solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Saving bulk is not supported in LightCouch API, however it's planned in the next release.

Comment: if that is a show stopper you can make a call use something like Apache Httpclient and Jackson to make make your bulk call to couch

Answer (score 3):

I decided to give it a go. I have a database holding documents that describe a person.

Here is my `Person` class which extends [`Document`](http://www.lightcouch.org/javadocs/org/lightcouch/Document.html) <sup>[LightCouch](http://www.lightcouch.org/)</sup>:

```
public class Person extends Document {

    private String firstname = "";
    private String lastname = "";
    private int age = -1;

    public Person(String firstname, String lastname, int age) {
        super();
        this.setFirstname(firstname);
        this.setLastname(lastname);
        this.setAge(age);
    }

    // setters and getters omitted for brevity

}
```

The algorithm is simple.

1. Create an array of type `Document`
2. Put your documents into the array
3. Create a HTTP POST request
4. Put the JSON converted array into the request body
5. Send it

Here is roughly what the code could look like.

*Note: try/catch omitted for brevity! Of course you are expected to use them.*

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // You could also use a List and then convert it to an array
    Document[] docs = new Document[2];
    docs[0] = new Person("John", "Smith", 34);
    docs[1] = new Person("Jane", "Smith", 30);

    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    // Note the _bulk_docs
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://127.0.0.1:5984/persons/_bulk_docs");

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    StringEntity data = 
        new StringEntity("{ \"docs\": " + gson.toJson(docs) + "}");
    data.setContentType("application/json");
    post.setEntity(data);

    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post);

    if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 201) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed. HTTP error code: "
            + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
    }
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader((response.getEntity().getContent())));
    String output;
    while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(output);
    }
    httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
}
```

I'll describe the two noteworthy parts in this example.

First one is the collection of documents. In this case I used an array instead of a `List` for the example.

```
Document[] docs = new Document[2];
docs[0] = new Person("John", "Smith", 34);
docs[1] = new Person("Jane", "Smith", 30);
```

You could use a `List` as well and later convert it to an array using Java's utility methods.

Second one is the `StringEntity`. As per CouchDB's documentation on the [HTTP Bulk Document API](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Bulk_Document_API#Modify_Multiple_Documents_With_a_Single_Request) on modify multiple documents with a single request the JSON structure of your request body should look like this.

```
{
  "docs": [
    DOCUMENT,
    DOCUMENT,
    DOCUMENT
  ]
}
```

This is the reason for the somewhat ugly `StringEntity` definition.

```
StringEntity data = new StringEntity("{ \"docs\": " + gson.toJson(docs) + "}");
```

As a response you'll get a JSON array containing objects whose fields represent the *_id* and *_rev* of the inserted document along with a transaction status indicator.

Answer (score 0):

I did the same thing but with spring Rest Template
I created a class which would hold the documents to be updated int he following way.

```
   public class BulkUpdateDocument {

    private List<Object> docs;
    }
```

My Rest code looks like this.

```
    BulkUpdateDocument doc = new BulkUpdateDocument(ListOfObjects);

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();
    header.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8);
    HttpEntity<?> requestObject = new HttpEntity<Object>(gson.toJson(doc), header);

    ResponseEntity<Object> postForEntity = restTemplate.postForEntity(path + "/_bulk_docs", requestObject, Object.class);
```